# Curl command in form of httpPost Java

Tags: java, curl, http-post, apache-commons-httpclient

Can someone help me write this as an httpPost in Java?
I just can't get it right

```
curl -X POST --user $YOUR_API_KEY_ID:$YOUR_API_KEY_SECRET \
 -H "Accept: application/json" \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8" \
 -d '{
       "favoriteColor": "red",
       "hobby": "Kendo"
     }' \
"https://api.stormpath.com/v1/accounts/cJoiwcorTTmkDDBsf02bAb/customData"
```

Thanks in advance

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost();
URI uri = new URI("https://api.stormpath.com/v1/applications/7Jl082Y0Rsff2IBmtL8q2F/accounts");
httpPost.setURI(uri);
httpPost.addHeader(BasicScheme.authenticate(
        new UsernamePasswordCredentials(id, secret),
        HTTP.UTF_8, false));

httpPost.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
httpPost.addHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(json[0].toString(), HTTP.UTF_8));

HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        inputStream));
```

I dont know if that helps ya out. Please someone help me write this curl command.  =( ahah hthanks again

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: i´ve tried multiple times. dont have the exact code, but this is one i wrote for another similar one: